# Pandas groupby having condition on column

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have data like this :

```
    userID  activity   count
0   3       running         5
1   3       running         6
2   3       walking         0
3   3       walking         1
4   3       stopped         2
```

I want to group data conditionallly, by userID and wether activity is running(1) or not (0)

This will group by userID, of course, I'm a newbie in Pandas!:

```
numUsers = df.groupby(by=["userID"])["count"].sum()
```

Comment: `numUsers = df.groupby(by=["userID",df["activity"].eq('running').astype(int)])["count"].sum()`

Comment: .eq is not working on UTF8, specially Arabic characters?

Comment: It should working well, but you can try `numUsers = df.groupby(by=["userID",(df["activity"] == 'running').astype(int)])["count"].sum()`